# Pyinstaller error_ lib not found

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I created the program with PyQt5 and used pyinstaller to make this code into an exe file. Now I have an exe file, but when I run it, I get an error like the one in the picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeb7w.png)

I thought it was a problem with the pyinstaller process, so I downloaded it again and looked at the warning and got the following error. No matter how hard I try, I can't resolve the error. Can anyone tell me how to resolve it?

```
95114 WARNING: No django root directory could be found!
103900 WARNING: Hidden import "django.db.backends.__pycache__.base" not found!
107726 WARNING: Hidden import "importlib_resources.trees" not found!
117667 WARNING: Hidden import "django.db.backends.oracle.compiler" not found!
123478 WARNING: get_package_paths - package pywin32_system32 has multiple paths (['C:\\Users\\wonjong\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\pywin32_system32', 'C:\\Users\\wonjong\\anaconda3\\envs\\geum\\lib\\site-packages\\pywin32_system32']); returning only first one!
137583 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'sycl6.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\wonjong\\anaconda3\\envs\\geum\\Library\\bin\\omptarget.sycl.wrap.dll'.
137584 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'pgc.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\wonjong\\anaconda3\\envs\\geum\\Library\\bin\\mkl_pgi_thread.2.dll'.
137584 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'pgf90.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\wonjong\\anaconda3\\envs\\geum\\Library\\bin\\mkl_pgi_thread.2.dll'.
137585 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'pgmath.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\wonjong\\anaconda3\\envs\\geum\\Library\\bin\\mkl_pgi_thread.2.dll'.
137585 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'msmpi.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\wonjong\\anaconda3\\envs\\geum\\Library\\bin\\mkl_blacs_msmpi_lp64.2.dll'.
137586 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'msmpi.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\wonjong\\anaconda3\\envs\\geum\\Library\\bin\\mkl_blacs_msmpi_ilp64.2.dll'.
```

I've tried adding it to hiddenimport, upgrading pyinstaller, and adding a hook to the path where the error is coming from, but it doesn't work.